# Reshape date columns in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to reshape data from wide to long format in R.  In wide form, my columns are dates, and I want to put these dates into rows.  My data are

```
structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 3L), B = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Site1", 
"Site2", "Site3"), class = "factor"), C = c(1L, 4L, 3L), D = c(7L, 
5L, 1L), X4.5.2013 = c(4L, 6L, 8L), X7.5.2013 = c(2L, 5L, 7L), 
X10.5.2013 = c(5L, 4L, 8L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"X4.5.2013", "X7.5.2013", "X10.5.2013"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

which gives this dataframe

```
  A     B C D X4.5.2013 X7.5.2013 X10.5.2013
1 1 Site1 1 7         4         2          5
2 4 Site3 4 5         6         5          4
3 3 Site2 3 1         8         7          8
```

Note that here, the columns are dates, so that for example X4.5.2013 corresponds to the date 4/5/2013.  I want to reshape these data to look like

```
structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), B = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Site1", "Site2", 
"Site3"), class = "factor"), C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), D = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Date = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("10/5/2013", "4/5/2013", 
"7/5/2013"), class = "factor"), E = c(4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
8L, 7L, 8L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "Date", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -9L))
```

or

```
  A     B C D      Date E
1 1 Site1 1 7  4/5/2013 4
2 1 Site1 1 7  7/5/2013 2
3 1 Site1 1 7 10/5/2013 5
4 4 Site3 4 5  4/5/2013 6
5 4 Site3 4 5  7/5/2013 5
6 4 Site3 4 5 10/5/2013 4
7 3 Site2 3 1  4/5/2013 8
8 3 Site2 3 1  7/5/2013 7
9 3 Site2 3 1 10/5/2013 8
```

I've been reading online and it seems I want to use the "reshape" command.  I've tried this

```
reshape(df1, varying = list(c("X4.5.2013", "X7.5.2013", "X10.5.2013")),
             idvar = "D", direction = "long")
```

which results in

```
    A     B C D time X4.5.2013
7.1 1 Site1 1 7    1         4
5.1 4 Site3 4 5    1         6
1.1 3 Site2 3 1    1         8
7.2 1 Site1 1 7    2         2
5.2 4 Site3 4 5    2         5
1.2 3 Site2 3 1    2         7
7.3 1 Site1 1 7    3         5
5.3 4 Site3 4 5    3         4
1.3 3 Site2 3 1    3         8
```

This seems to work somewhat, however it gives me a "time" column when I instead want these times to be the dates from the column headings in the original dataframe.  Does anyone know how I can use the column headings for this "time" column -- but instead calling this column "Date" and converting the column headings into date formats, as in my second dataframe posted above?

Thanks!

EDIT: After playing with it a bit more, I found that

```
reshape(df1, varying=list(c("X4.5.2013", "X7.5.2013", "X10.5.2013")), times=names(df1[5:7]), timevar = "Date", idvar="D", direction = "long")
```

results in

```
             A     B C D       Date X4.5.2013
7.X4.5.2013  1 Site1 1 7  X4.5.2013         4
5.X4.5.2013  4 Site3 4 5  X4.5.2013         6
1.X4.5.2013  3 Site2 3 1  X4.5.2013         8
7.X7.5.2013  1 Site1 1 7  X7.5.2013         2
5.X7.5.2013  4 Site3 4 5  X7.5.2013         5
1.X7.5.2013  3 Site2 3 1  X7.5.2013         7
7.X10.5.2013 1 Site1 1 7 X10.5.2013         5
5.X10.5.2013 4 Site3 4 5 X10.5.2013         4
1.X10.5.2013 3 Site2 3 1 X10.5.2013         8
```

This is very close to what I want, but is still not perfect.  Here are the issues I still have:

1) How can I change the name of the last column from "X4.5.2013" to "E"?  Is there a way in the reshape command, or do I have to do this with a separate command after reshaping?
2) Why are the indexes in this last dataframe of the format "7.X4.5.2013" (for example)?

Comment: One other idea. `reshape` tries to create names for columns using dashes or dots , so try setting sep="" to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `time` variable to select from the vector of columnnames where `df2` is the result of the first reshape command that you offered.

```
df2$time <- as.Date( 
              sub("X","", c("X4.5.2013", "X7.5.2013", "X10.5.2013"))[
                                                             df2$time], 
                    format="%m.%d.%Y")
df2

    A     B C D       time X4.5.2013
7.1 1 Site1 1 7 2013-04-05         4
5.1 4 Site3 4 5 2013-04-05         6
1.1 3 Site2 3 1 2013-04-05         8
7.2 1 Site1 1 7 2013-07-05         2
5.2 4 Site3 4 5 2013-07-05         5
1.2 3 Site2 3 1 2013-07-05         7
7.3 1 Site1 1 7 2013-10-05         5
5.3 4 Site3 4 5 2013-10-05         4
1.3 3 Site2 3 1 2013-10-05         8
```

If you prefer to work on the resutls of the second reshape operation (which I named `df3`) then do this:

```
df3$Date <- as.Date( sub("X","", df3$Date) , format="%m.%d.%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help DWin, but this doesn't seem to reshape the data in my original dataframe.  I'm obviously not following what you mean, can you please explain this to me a bit more (I'm sorry for not following, but as you can see, I'm not very good at R).

Comment: I can also "fix" the result of the second one.

Comment: Hi DWin, I understand what you mean now.  The second reshape operation  with your second suggestion seems to be the easiest solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: DWin, when I apply this to my real data, I get an error "Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(d[, idvar], times[1L],  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"  Any suggestion?

Comment: The error is coming from the `reshape` operation. You will need to post more information about the dataframe. Perhaps duplicates in column names?

Comment: Hello DWin, I do not see any duplicates in the column names.  I have also tried "new.row.names = NULL" and get the same error.  :(

Comment: Well, I did say we would need more information. I'm not going to guess anymore.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33316/discussion-between-thomas-and-dwin)

Comment: DWin, thanks for your help.  It seems that I had duplicate values in column D, so this was resulting in duplicate rownames when combined with the date columns.  Problem solved.  Thanks again for your help.